# Match All Data Between certain sting pattern PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays

In php I have an array that contains a list of publishers and books.  The array looks like this

```
[p]DARK HORSE COMICS
[c]ADVENTURES INTO THE UNKNOWN ARCHIVES HC VOL 03   $49.99
[c]BALTIMORE INFERNAL TRAIN #1  $3.50
[c]BLOOD BLOCKADE BATTLEFRONT TP VOL 04     $12.99
[p]DC COMCIS
[c]BATMAN #23 VOL 03 $3.99
[p]IMAGE COMICS
[c]SAGA #35 #2.99
```

The pattern is the publisher is listed first and the "[p]" tag indicates that is is the publisher.  What follows is list of books that the publisher is issuing that month denoted by a [c].  The pattern starts again  publisher...books...publisher....books

I want to find all the books between the [p] delimiters and insert them into the appropriate database based on publisher.  All of the Dark Horse books go into the Dark Horse database all of the DC Comics books go into the DC Comics data base.

I know that I can probably use a preg_match to look for the [p] but I'm not sure how to find all the [c] tags between the [p] tags and tell it to stop searching once it hits that second [p] tag.

I'm thinking something like this maybe

Find all individual books by the publishers and build an array

```
look for first publisher using the [p] tag
...
find all books by first publisher using [c] tag
...
build array for first publisher
...
$darkHorse[] = "all dark horse books"
...
run into next [p] tag and stop matching books
...
look for next publisher using the next [p] tag
...
find all books for next publisher using [c] tag
...
build array for next publisher
...
$dcComics = "all dc comic books"
... 
repeat...
```

The [p] and [c] tags are arbitrary.  I just inserted those to denote the differences between the publisher and book.

I'm then certain that I can take those individual arrays and insert them into my SQL database.

THanks for any tips

Comment: That doesn't look much like an array to me, are you sure it isn't just a string?

Comment: Sounds good. I'd code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
$currentPublisher = "";
foreach ($file as $line) {
    if (substr($line,0,3) == "[p]")
        $currentPublisher = substr($line,4);
    else if (substr($line,0,3) == "[c]") {
        // add book with $currentPublisher
    }
}
```

Just save the last found publisher in a variable and use it for all books. When the next publisher is found it will be updated.